# Should a complex question be formulated as to be understandable by people with no expert knowledge on the subject?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148011/) on Stack Overflow and (all) I got is a comment saying that the question is off topic and a "close" vote.

I reckon that to someone that doesn't have knowledge of both Unity3D, v4l2 and gstreamer, this might seem a operative system related question.

However if someone **has** knowledge of said systems, he would immediately understand that this is in fact a programming related question. Even **if** the solution is some different settings in the gstreamer pipeline, it comes from understanding/debugging of the Unity3D part (anyway, gstreamer is a framework and writing a pipeline in the terminal is just a shorthand method to get it run, so arguably writing a gstreamer pipeline **is** programming).

The confusion here arises probably by the fact that I didn't include the code of the Unity3D application. But again, if you know I was talking about, you know that the WebCamTexture has few option and it works just fine with the default settings usually, so you don't need the code to know what it's happening. If you know the answer to this question, you will know what I need to change in my code without reading it.

I think. I could be wrong of course, but that's beside the point.

Should I expand my question to make it clear to people that have no direct knowledge on the matter (and therefore no chance of answering the question) that this is a legitimate programming question?

Or should people that have no skill and knowledge to fully understand the question (like, [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=1), the author of the comment) restrain from commenting, upvoting, downvoting, close-voting things that they don't comprehend?

Comment: It looks on-topic as far as topicality goes, but it seems like you're missing a [Minimal, Complete. and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), though I don't know much on the topic so I may be wrong on that. Maybe just verify that you can reproduce the issue on a clean system using only the information provided in your question. Possibly include any hardware specs that may be relevant, and the specific distribution of Linux and version that you are using

Comment: Your last paragraph is on the edge of rude. And I can see why they close voted the way they do and an MCVE would have prevent that confusion, specially if it is that trivial as you claim.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. Programming is a large discipline and no one has the skill to comprehend everything. The person that commented seems to be an expert in SSL an C++, two things I don't know virtually nothing about and i won't touch a question about them with a four feet pole

Comment: About the MCVE. Ok, i understand your point. I could have included it with a link of the standard example of WebCamTexture in the Unity3D documentation. But it seems more a formality that something really useful.

Comment: Sometimes it takes an expert to know that a question is not a programming question.  That however does not make the question off topic, not everybody is an expert.  "Your machine/OS/config is messed up" is a very common answer here.  Very little point in fretting over just one close vote, it takes five.

Answer (score 3):

> Should a complex question be formulated as to be understandable by people with no expert knowledge on the subject?

It should be formulated in a way that someone that knows the answer can identify that they know the answer and have all elements to answer it. Basically, that is clear and complete.

BTW, I understand the question, but I'm unable to answer it (I think you are trying to duplicate the device), and it actually looks like a general computing question. It doesn't even use the gstreamer api calls (they have for Python and C that I'm aware of), [but the tool](https://people.freedesktop.org/~tsaunier/gstreamer-website/gst-launch.html) gst-launch.

Unless you can present a strong case that it needs a programmer to understand the question (I'm not one), it will be a general computing question asked by someone that seems to have read the manual.

Comment: On a third read, it says "the application" on several places, but is not clear which application is being talked about?

Comment: Also, equally important, the question should be formulated in such a way that people who are Googling for the question (who are likely not experts) will be able to see that they are experiencing the same problem, and that the question will help them.

Comment: Gst-launch is just a handy way to construct a pipeline. It IS calling the gstreamer API. If you ever programmed in gstreamer you would know that you usually put down things that way then translate them in what programming language you are using. Also, the solution it's still probably in some setting in the unity WebCamTexture. And that is unmistakably programming.

Comment: People that are looking for that will search for "v4l2loopback unity3d" and find that question, then they will undertand it because they know how gstreamer, Unity3D and v4l2 works, otherwise they could not think that this is even possible to do.

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso as life has it, I have programmed using gstreamer python library, and you don't seem to be using anything like that. You are complain that "the application", doesn't seems to do what you want which is read from the cloned an video source that you created. Until there is either unclear (what the application is?) or off topic (the tool doesn't do what I want).

Comment: Then you should know that that pipeline is nothing more than glorified syntactic sugar for a program written using gstreamer. Also "the application" is simply a generic application in unity3d that open a webcam. The example in the unity3d doc, if you like. It doesn't matter,  the interface is so simple that if the change has to be made there, you don't need to read the code to point me to the answer. You only need the provided log (i think)

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso why don't  you include that "generic application" instead and lets us whenever is relevant or not. Actually, why don't you post the actual code to reproduce the problem instead of discussing here whenever is that people should understand the question and what not? Your question should be "**clear and complete**"